# How to Refrence java file in android layout .xml for a coustom Viewgroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

In my application I want to create one Search widget which would be Reusable as .java file , i need to reflect it into layout.xml file so that i can use it. Directly.....Here is my code having one edit box , two buttons.

```
public class SearchWidget extends ViewGroup{

    Context mContext;
    LinearLayout layout;
    EditText edit;
    Button searchButton;
    Button clear;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    public SearchWidget(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext=context;
        layout=new LinearLayout(context);
        edit=new EditText(context);
        searchButton=new Button(context);
        clear=new Button(context);
        params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);
        edit.setMaxLines(1);
        edit.setWidth(100);
        layout.addView(searchButton);
        layout.addView(clear);
    }

}
```

Please Suggest me how to give reference of this java file to my layout.xml 
   Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it by using your package name along with the file name like

```
<com.myapp.SearchWidget android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</com.myapp.SearchWidget>
```

When you use the xml to put your custom view, you need to use the constructor with 2 parameters.

After checking your code, there are many mistakes such as you are finally not adding 'layout' to the search widget. So nothing will show up. Im not sure what your end result is. But this is what I think you are trying to do.

```
public class SearchWidget extends LinearLayout {
    public SearchWidget(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);      
            EditText edit = new EditText(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams elp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
        edit.setLayoutParams(elp);

        Button searchButton = new Button(context);
        searchButton.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        searchButton.setText("Search");

        Button clearButton = new Button(context);
        clearButton.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        clearButton.setText("Clear");

        addView(edit);
        addView(searchButton);
        addView(clearButton);       
    }
}
```

Here I extended the LinearLayout

Comment: Hi @Blessenm i got this, but Now i`m not getting my Layout screen it is showing only Black Screen , can you provide any link where complete example is given Thanks....

Comment: it is Not solved the problem by applying this......there is only black screen being displayed///

Answer (score 0):

In you xml code. Add complete package name before class name to reference and then add you class name e.g

```
<com.my.test.SearchWidget
            android:id="@+id/large_photo_gallery"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package yourpackage;
... ...
public class SearchWidget extends ViewGroup
{
    // Please use this constructor.
    public SearchWidget(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    ... ...
}


<yourpackage.SearchWidget 
    android:id="@+id/searchWidget"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```